# How to create import to CodeQL

Tags: c++, codeql, semmle-ql

I want to create an import to my CodeQL query.
I want that this import will be named `Utils` and I will created inside it a predicate named `isNumber`.

How can I creat such import?

This how I want my code to look like:

```
import cpp
import Utils

where
    if exists(...)
    then isNumber(size.(VariableAccess).getTarget())
    else ...
select ...
```

I don't know how I create the `Utils` import, it writes:

> Could not resolve module Utils

I tried to create a folder named `Utils` near my code query (`code.ql`) but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found how to do it.
Need to create a file named `Utils.qll` in the same folder of your CodeQL query.

This is its code:

```
import cpp

predicate isNumber(Variable v){
    v.getUnspecifiedType() instanceof IntegralType
}
```